# ons-back-buttonのカスタマイズについて

Tags: onsen-ui

ons-back-buttonをons-buttonに使用しているCSSと同様のカスタマイズを行いたいと思いますが、
modifierによる方法が使えないためどのように行えばいいか、教えていただけますでしょうか？